# Resources on Master Equations

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, complex-systems, stochastic-processes

Presently I am reading about "Introduction to dynamical process theory and simulation" which uses the notion of [Master Equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_equation) to solve Markov process. 
I am very new to this. Can someone provide me the references so that I can learn about master equations from scratch.

Comment: Please see [this meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed/) about how to properly format resource recommendation questions.

Comment: I think the most obvious first source would probably be van Kampen's Stochastic Processes in Physics and Chemistry.

Comment: @alarge,I was just about to mention van Kampen's great work! Why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a brief notes is a better introduction than a whole book, because you directly go to some essential ideas (if the notes are good of course). Then, you can expand your knowledge later. Particularly, I liked some [course notes](http://ifisc.uib-csic.es/raul/CURSOS/SP/) by Raúl Toral, notes that I have found just by chance.

Answer (score 0):

John Baez has freely available [book](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/stoch_stable.pdf) based on a series of internet articles [articles](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/networks/). I is very readable and definitely starts from scratch.